# How can i configure openVPN server through java

Tags: java, networking, vpn, openvpn, openvpn-connect

I want to develop a Java desktop application that can establish a VPN connection with OpenVPN server. When a new user downloads my application, it should automatically set up a VPN connection with the OpenVPN server. Essentially, I aim to create my own OpenVPN client in Java.

Could someone outline the steps or flow to achieve this goal?